# How can I set the position of a paused video

Tags: wpf, video

I am using WPF's MediaElement. If the MediaElement is playing, setting the Position works as expected.

However, if the MediaElement is paused, setting the Position has no effect.

How can I set the position of a paused video?

Answer (score 1):

To update frames for seek operations while paused you need to set the [ScrubbingEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.scrubbingenabled.aspx) property of the media element to `true`. Ie (xaml):

```
<MediaElement x:Name="Player"
              LoadedBehavior="Manual"
              UnloadedBehavior="Manual"
              ScrubbingEnabled="True" />
```

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.scrubbingenabled.aspx)